# Keydown while mouseover and variables in multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, mouseover, keydown

When the cursor is moved while the "A" key is held, I want a variable flag to be set.

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function () {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 65){
            var $mLeft = '3px',
                $mTop = event.pageY - $sidebarRightDisp;
        } else {
            var $mLeft = event.pageX - $sidebarLeftDisp,
            $mTop = event.pageY - $sidebarRightDisp;
        }
    });
    var $boxStyleAct = 'left:' + $mLeft + 'px;top:' + $mTop + 'px' + ';';
    var $boxAct = '<li style="' + $boxStyleAct + '"></li>';

    $(".boxes").append($boxAct);
});
```

By the way, I really can't put my "// do something with x" inside the keydown function.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `x` variable is defined within the scope of the if statements. You could move it out. You're also adding an event listener on mousemove which isn't good.

You could instead do something like this.

```js
var aPressed = false;
var keyPressed = false;
var sidebarRightDisp = 5;
var sidebarLeftDisp = 5;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  if (!keyPressed)
    return;

  var mLeft, mTop;
  if (aPressed) {
    mLeft = '3px';
    mTop = event.pageY - sidebarRightDisp;
  } else {
    mLeft = event.pageX - sidebarLeftDisp;
    mTop = event.pageY - sidebarRightDisp;
  }

  var boxStyleAct = 'left:' + mLeft + 'px;top:' + mTop + 'px' + ';';
  var boxAct = '<li style="' + boxStyleAct + '"></li>';

  $(".boxes").append(boxAct);

}).keydown(function(e) {
  keyPressed = true;
  aPressed = e.which == 65;

}).keyup(function(e) {
  keyPressed = false;
  aPressed = false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boxes">
</div>
```

Comment: I just change my code to show you a better example of what I want. I am not sure that your solution works

Comment: It's hard to say what you need to do without seeing the complete HTML/CSS. Does the updated version do what you want?

Comment: I have just a `<div class="boxes"></div>` and I wan't to add a `<div class="box"></div>` inside of it

Comment: It works! But I changed the `(!keypressed)` part. I changed it to                    `if (keyPressed) {
      var mLeft, mTop;
      if (aPressed) {
        mLeft = '3px';
        mTop = event.pageY - sidebarRightDisp;
      } else {
        mLeft = event.pageX - sidebarLeftDisp;
        mTop = event.pageY - sidebarRightDisp;
      }
  } else {
      mLeft = event.pageX - sidebarLeftDisp;
        mTop = event.pageY - sidebarRightDisp;
  }`

Comment: That's great! Sounds like you don't need the keyPressed variable. You could just get rid of that and the else part and the result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var AkeyPressed = false;
var status = document.getElementById('status');

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
  if(AkeyPressed == true) {
    console.log("mouse moving while pressing A key");
  }
  else {
    console.log("A key not pressed ");
  }
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 65) {
    AkeyPressed = true;
    //var x = true;
  }
  else {
    AkeyPressed = false;
    //var x = false;
  }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  AkeyPressed = false;
});
window.focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```